Как настроить блок AllowedIPs в wireguard на ОС: Fedora 40 или Ubuntu 24.04?
Сразу оговорю в Windows, такой проблемы нет. Проверял на последних версиях Ubuntu и Fedora, где была добавлена возможность настраивать wireguard на вкладке Networks в настройках. Имеется конфиг:
[Interface]
PrivateKey = ...............
Address = 10.138.98.2/32
DNS = 8.8.8.8

[Peer]
PublicKey = ...............
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = 146.0.78.177:37956

Такой конфиг работает везде: Windows, Ubuntu, Linux. Но мне нужно работа VPN на определенных VPN. Я пытаюсь их указать в блоке "AllowedIPs": 192.168.1.1/16, 192.168.1.1/24, 192.168.1.1/32 (маска может быть везде 16 или 24 или 32, без разницы если маска отлична от 0 - vpn перестает работаеть), то есть такой конфиг:
[Interface]
PrivateKey = ...............
Address = 10.138.98.2/32
DNS = 8.8.8.8

[Peer]
PublicKey = ...............
AllowedIPs = 192.168.1.1/16, 192.168.1.1/24, 192.168.1.1/32
Endpoint = 146.0.78.177:37956

Работает только на Windows. Всем может быть проблема и есть идеи, как это исправить?
